# Cannot upload bigger (1 GB) file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload

Unable to upload bigger files greater than 250 MB in SharePoint Online document library.

I have tried without custom columns I can able to upload where as with custom columns unable to upload. If I upload getting error displayed as below.

> The webpage at https://siteurl/_layouts/15/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7b2A6CE6D1-DCB6-4087-9E99-CBDE9E0DC618%7d&RootFolder=&IsDlg=1 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a setting in central admin web app general settings to increase maximum upload size. Have you tried that?

Comment: This is for sharepoint online, we don't have this setting in sharepoint online i guess.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to sync the library with your onedrive client and upload the file via that client.

[image]

And then add the file to the synced folder in your file explorer.

Comment: we have some columns to fill  after uploading the file, may be tedious job to user to sync with one drive then edit the properties of that file.